# Copying data to new sheet if it contains certain data

Tags: excel, vba, import-from-csv

I want to pull certain data out of a report and spit it out in a new sheet.

I have been able to, pull the data out of a text file and paste to a new sheet in the template, find the spot I need to start looking for relevant data, and paste the first line into the target sheet.

I am wondering about a more sophisticated way to set up the code. I think a loop might be best but an array might also do the trick.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub findandmovetxt()

'finding text data and moving to new sheet

    Dim celltxt As String

    Sheets("BAI").Activate
    Cells.find(what:="811", After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    Cells.find(what:="16,175", After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Bank").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("BAI").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    celltxt = ActiveCell.Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "16,175") = True Then Selection.Copy
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "16,175") = False Then End

End Sub
```

The relevant data is part of a large bank report. I want to copy the lines that contain "16,175" within the "811" account and paste them to the 'bank' sheet.

After the "16,175" rows there is always a "16,275" that I don't want to pick up and signals the end of the "16,175" data in the relevant account.

I will eventually use the same code for other bank accounts that are further down in the report.

I need to know how to utilize a loop (or array) but unsure how to implement in this situation because I want to focus on data within the specific account and not necessarily the overall report.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub findandmovetxt()

Dim wbBankReport As Workbook: Set wbBankReport = ThisWorkbook 'This assumes the data you want to look at is in the same workbook that contains your code.

'The next two lines require that your workbook already contains a worksheet named "BAI" and a worksheet named "Bank".
'Typically you would write error handling code to ensure these tabs exist and to create them if they don't.
Dim wsBAI As Worksheet: Set wsBAI = wbBankReport.Worksheets("BAI") 'This tells the code where your BAI data is.
Dim wsBANK As Worksheet: Set wsBANK = wbBankReport.Worksheets("Bank") 'This tells the code where you want to put your data.
Dim i0 As Long 'This is a counter you will use to cycle through the lines.
Dim i1 As Long: i1 = 1 'This is a counter you will use to add lines to the Bank tab.
Dim strLine As String 'This is a variable that will contain the data from each line.
Dim blnCOPY As Boolean 'This is a variable that will tell the code when to copy and when to stop.

With wsBAI
    For i0 = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'This says you want to start at row 1 and go to the end of the populated lines in your BAI worksheet.
        strLine = .Cells(i0, 1).Value 'This copies the value of each cell into the variable.
        If InStr(strLine, ",811,") > 0 Then blnCOPY = True
            'Instead of just looking for 811, the InStr function (In String) is looking for 811 preceded and followed by a comma just in case the series 811 appears anywhere else that might throw your search off.
            'Setting the variable blnCOPY to TRUE tells the code you want to copy the appropriate following lines.
        If InStr(strLine, "16,175,") > 0 And blnCOPY = True Then
            wsBANK.Cells(i1, 1).Value = strLine 'This moves the data to the Bank worksheet.
            i1 = i1 + 1 'This increments the row number.
        End If
        If InStr(strLine, "16,275,") > 0 Then blnCOPY = False 'This tells the code you don't want to copy any lines until it sees the ",811," again.
    Next i0
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works really well for me, with a few tweaks. I appreciate the help - Boolean argument very useful for this application. First time i'll use it in code. Need to study the syntax. Thanks Pondersome